# What is the symmetry element for translational symmetry operation?

Tags: solid-state-physics, symmetry, crystals

I am learning about basics of solid state physics and currently learning about symmetry concepts. If I got it right, all Bravais lattices have translational symmetry. This property is basically implied from the definition of Bravais lattice and all of them have it. Beside translational symmetry, lattices may also have other symmetries (eg. rotational) but don't have to. So far so good, now let me quote some text from one page:

> A symmetry operation is an action that leaves an object looking the
>   same after it has been carried out. Each symmetry operation has a
>   corresponding symmetry element, which is the axis, plane, line or
>   point with respect to which the symmetry operation is carried out.

Source: [Symmetry Operations and Symmetry Elements](https://chem.libretexts.org/Textbook_Maps/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Map%3A_Symmetry_(Vallance)/02._Symmetry_operations_and_symmetry_elements)

So if axis (or straight line) is the symmetry element for rotation and if plane is the symmetry element for reflection, what is the symmetry element for translation?

Note:  I don't have previous formal knowledge about symmetry or group theory so nonrigorous explanation is preferred.

Comment: Going by the definition on the linked page, which is "The symmetry element consists of all the points that stay in the same place when the symmetry operation is performed", I think that a translation has no symmetry element.